# TextView setText raise application suspending

Tags: android, textview, settext

These are my code, I run these code in AsyncTask onPostExcute function.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from( this.context );
    LinearLayout layout = ( LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null, false);
    layout.addView(layout);
    View view = (View) layout;

     ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(badge);
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
    titleUi.setText(title);
```

when the application run to here, no error and responding

here is my xml file named custom_info_window.xml contents

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:contentDescription="@string/info_window"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I try to dispaly this view as a child view of Mainactivity after AsyncTask executed
but it did not work.
There is no error or warning.
I set breakpoint at the line "titleUi.setText("1312")", when the application run to here, there is no responding. It looks like dead.

anyone can help me?
Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to post the whole AsyncTask code here. I think the fault is in the below part of your code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from( this.context );
LinearLayout layout = ( LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null, false);
layout.addView(layout);
View view = (View) layout;
```

Try this instead,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(badge);
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
    titleUi.setText(title);
```

Comment: Please up-vote and accept my answer if it solved your issue, so that anyone will know the issue was resolved. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the DEBUGGER to try and pinpoint further what is going on.

Or use :

```
Log.e("Log Title","message");
```